# BackboneCollection.Unshift(NewItem) - not working

Tags: backbone.js, knockout.js

i have a Backbone collection and it was hold by a knockback.ObservableCollection and i want to add he new items on the Top just like Array.Shift(NewItem). Is there anyway to do that? i pretty new with backbonejs

```
  this.recentItemList = kb.collectionObservable(recentItems, {
                view_model: RecentItemViewModel, sort_attribute: 'modifiedDateTime'
            });



var options = {};
        var self = this;

        var newRecentItem = new recentItem
        ({
            recentId: model.get("id"),
            recentName: model.get("description"),
            type: "test"
        });

        options.success = function ()
        {
            self.recentItems.unshift(newRecentItem);
        };

        newRecentItem.save({}, options);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, my mistakes.

so i just removed the sort_attribute and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Make your viewModel variable a ko.observableArray, and you can then just variableName.unshift(newElement);